# Android, HttpURLConnection and handling bad credentials

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm performing a GET request:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
urlConnection.connect();
```

by which time the credentials have already been set with:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     return new PasswordAuthentication(loginNameString, passwordString.toCharArray());
  }
});
```

Everything works fine when I supply good credentials (i.e. username and password).

What happens to the connection when bad credentials are supplied? For example, if I deliberately supply bad credentials and I call `urlConnection.getResponseCode()` immediately after `urlConnection.connect()` my app eventually times out and I have to force close. Why is that?

** Edit. So far as I can tell, the HttpURLConnection just keeps trying to connect (even with a finite timeout) when the credentials are bad. (I know this because I added the line `Log.v("Authentication", "Calling...");` in my `getPasswordAuthentication()` method before returning). I want the connection to stop trying if it fails for bad credentials!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Basic auth, the workaround is:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Using `android.util.Base64` package. Also note that the `encodeToString()` method is available since API 8 (Android 2.2).

Also, http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7058 is relevant.

Comment: thank you! that bug 7058 in aosp is exactly it - we are supposed to be asking the user for a new set of credentials because they previous ones failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue using a flag and returning a `null` in your authenticator after your first wrong authentication.

In this way your `InputStream` will raise an exception that you can handle thereafter.

Copying from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13615011/628713:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    private boolean alreadyTriedAuthenticating = false;
    private URL url;

    ...

    public void send()
    {
        HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                if (!alreadyTriedAuthenticating)
                {
                    alreadyTriedAuthenticating = true;
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that setting `Authorization` header results in a 400 response code on 2.3.7 so here's a tweaked Authenticator instead:

```
public class FixedAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private PasswordAuthentication passAuth;

    public FixedAuthenticator(PasswordAuthentication passAuth) {
        this.passAuth = passAuth;
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        try {
            return passAuth;
        } finally {
            passAuth = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to set a fresh instance of it before connecting:

```
...
Authenticator.setDefault(new FixedAuthenticator(passAuth));
connection.connect();
```

[A working example](https://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts/blob/develop/extra/src/org/droidparts/http/worker/HttpURLConnectionWorker.java).